# How to correct the string returned based on a regex

Tags: java, regex

Here is the `message` and  `Type`

| message | Type |
| --- | --- |
| IND SMD 0402 1.2nH 50pH 390mA 100MOHM | MAG |

What i'm trying to return is the `1.2nH`

For that i created a function as below

```
public static String SplitStringValue1(String message,String type ) {

String[] SplitMessage = message.split(" ");
String ch="";

if (type.equals("MAG"))
   { 
      if (SplitMessage[0].matches("IND\\d(.*)")||SplitMessage[0].equals("IND")||SplitMessage[0].matches("SELF\\d(.*)")||SplitMessage[0].equals("SELF"))
      {
          
         if (SplitMessage[1].equals("SMD"))
         { 
               
         for (int j=0;j<SplitMessage.length;j++)
         {
            if ((SplitMessage[j].matches("(-)*\\d*(\\.)?\\d*(\\/)?\\d*(.)?d*(UH|uH|MH|mH|nH|NH|H|h)")&&SplitMessage[j].length()<15))
            {
                ch=SplitMessage[j];  
            }
         }
         }
      }
    
   }

return   ch;
}
```

This is returning me `50pH` but actually i'm trying to return  `1.2nH`

How could i correct my function ?

Comment: `(.)` => `(\.)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the code to check if the type is `MAG`, you can use a bit more specific pattern to get the value `1.2nH` with a single capture group

```
^IND\b.*?\h(\d*\.?\d+(?:(?:[UuMmNn])?H|h))\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `IND\b` Match the word IND
- `.*?\h` Match as least as possible chars and then a space
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d*\.?\d+` Match 1+ digits with an option decimal part
  - `(?:(?:[UuMmNn])?H|h)` Match `UH` `uH` etc.. or just `H` or `h`
- `)`  Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EQyfRI/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^IND\\b.*?\\h(\\d*\\.?\\d+(?:(?:[UuMmNn])?H|h))\\b";
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UcTj4Z)